# Sql query two first rows group by userId

Tags: sql

I have the data like this

```
deviceId | userId | Time
20       | 1      | 2-Jan-18
21       | 1      | 2-Jan-19
22       | 1      | 2-Jan-10
30       | 2      | 2-Jan-18
30       | 2      | 2-Jan-19
```

I would like to query 2 first devices that the user uses and also the time (group by userId)

```
userId|firstDeviceId|firstDeviceTime|secondDeviceId|secondDeviceTime
1     |20           | 2-Jan-18      | 21           | 2-Jan-19
2     |30           | 2-Jan-18      | 30           | 2-Jan-19
```

Could you guys show me the way to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A typical method uses `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select userid,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then deviceid end) as deviceid_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then devicetime end) as devicetime_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then deviceid end) as deviceid_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then devicetime end) as devicetime_2
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by userid order by device time desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2
group by userid;
```